# How can I read a rsa public key form string(Generate by java and I want to read it with Python)

Tags: java, python-3.x, rsa, public-key-encryption

The code generate the public key is

```
    public static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    public static final String RSA_ALGORITHM = "RSA";


    public static Map<String, String> createKeys(int keySize){
        KeyPairGenerator kpg;
        try{
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such algorithm-->[" + RSA_ALGORITHM + "]");
        }

        kpg.initialize(keySize);

        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        Key publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        String publicKeyStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(publicKey.getEncoded());

        Key privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        String privateKeyStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(privateKey.getEncoded());
        Map<String, String> keyPairMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        keyPairMap.put("publicKey", publicKeyStr);
        keyPairMap.put("privateKey", privateKeyStr);

        return keyPairMap;
    }


    public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(publicKey));
        RSAPublicKey key = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
        return key;
    }
```

The key is then send to me, and I want to read it with python importKey(). But I always get the error "RSA key format is not supported".

The key is "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDGrLFBqubzi45M_yxs5Ps4XW3DIOeAo5x7Ca9EYmWAig3Rb3Efm2PCgipwNube2Ae5eUI5dYlQW32FSF81rw7vNdwfODDzITyWRPLEuVbBbkF5zD6kTxycqlVbH-uTyb95181jpY_XY6tmEOCZCq3mZhil9VA4ZvAoSBcJ8muXaQIDAQAB"

After searching with Google, I've try to add header "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" to it and nothing different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using a 'URLsafe' base64 encoder, although not the standard Java one. 'URLsafe' uses different characters (for code values 62 and 63) and no padding, and no linebreaks. PEM format (which was designed long before URLsafe encoding existed, indeed over a year before URLs existed!) uses the traditional base64 characters (now associated mostly with MIME), with padding, and with linebreaks (every 64 characters). Although not all software *checks* for linebreaks; you don't say which Python crypto library you are using (there are several) so I can't check if it cares about this point.

   In Java 8 up you can use [`Base64.getMimeEncoder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getMimeEncoder--) to handle most of these, but if you are stuck on older Java (see below) and/or some other library, you'll have to give details about it. You *could* convert the `- _` characters to `+ /`, add `=` padding to a multiple of 4, and add linebreaks if and as needed.

   OTOH the Python libs I've looked at accept 'DER' (i.e. binary) as well as PEM, so you could just decode the base64 (many decoders can handle lack of padding and at least some can handle both charsets with or without specification) and use that as-is.
2. The publickey encoding used by Java (which it imprecisely calls `"X.509"`) and also by OpenSSL and some other things is generic and includes an algorithm identifier, so the correct PEM labels are `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `------END PUBLIC KEY-----` (NO `RSA`).
3. You don't say what Java you use, but it apparently defaulted to 1024-bit for RSA, which is obsolete for several years and is no longer considered to provide adequate safety margin (although there are no open reports *yet* of actually *breaking* it). 2048 is now widely considered the minimum, and some applications or environments for various reasons use more. But deciding what crypto parameters to use (and indeed whether your application should even be using RSA, and if so which variant) are not programming questions and offtopic for SO; they belong on either [crypto.SX](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) (for the underlying principles) or [security.SX](https://security.stackexchange.com/) (for applications).

Comment: Thx very much. I use Java8, and I've tried M2Crypto and pycryptodome. I think what you say may be helpful. I will try it and after I get the result I will make another comment. Thx again. Very professional

Comment: cheers!!! It works! I modify the java code to get rid of 'URLsafe' and miracle occurs!!!! Thx